# Uniform boundedness of a family of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that the map $\lambda\to T(\lambda)$ from the domain $\{0<|\lambda|\leq 1\}\subset \mathbb{C}$ to the space of bounded operators on a Banach space $B$, . And further suppose that $T(0)$ is also bounded on $B$, does this imply that the $T(\lambda)$ is uniformly bound on the domain $\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}:|\lambda|\leq 1\}$?

Here, the continuity of $T(\lambda)$ at $\lambda=0$ may fail. I want to know if the condition $T(0)$ is bounded is sufficient to obtain the uniform boundedness. Thanks very much.

Comment: $B(0,1)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda|<1\}$, yes? So how are the operators to be defined on the boundary $|\lambda|=1$?

Comment: @uniquesolution No, it's the closed unit ball.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example: $X$ is any Banach space, and for $\lambda\neq 0$,

$$T(\lambda)(x)={x\over|\lambda|}\enspace\forall x\in X$$

Assume also $T(0)x=x$ for each $x\in X$.

Then the family $T(\lambda)$ is not uniformly bounded, so you do need continuity at $\lambda=0$.